# How to add only footer in checkout page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, footer

How can I add only footer section in my checkout page
I tried this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"> 
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

But this gives me header and footer both
I am not able to get footer alone.

Comment: just keep `<referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>` code inside body tag

Comment: I tried didn’t work

Comment: what the file name and path for above code ?

Comment: Checkout_index_index  and it's in Magento_checkout module which I override

Comment: please add above file at `{Package}\{theme}\Magento_Checkout\layout\override\theme\Magento\blank` and try once.

Answer (score 1):

You can this code in your theme file :-

> app/design/frontend/Magento/THEME/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true" />
</body>
```

i hope this will helpful.